# How to know MaxFailedPayments has reahced from IPN message?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I am working on the paypal recurring payment and I have set the MaxFailedPayments as 3. I want to send email to user when the this maximum failed payment has reahced 3. So from which status field in the IPN message ,we can understand MaxFailedPayments has reached ?

Thanks in advance

Boney

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "txn_type" value that tells you when a Recurring Profile reaches it maximum failed payment attempt limit - `txn_type=recurring_payment_suspended_due_to_max_failed_payment`

You can use that to trigger your notice to buyers.

You should receive an IPN post when the payment fails - `txn_type=recurring_payment_failed`
Trigger a notice to send out after two failed payment IPN posts arrive instead of waiting for the third failure and the Profile going into a suspended status.

Comment: At what intervals paypal tries to deduct payment from my account. Say first IPN message is "recurring_payment_failed". When does the next IPN comes. Can I specify this interval

Comment: We'll try to rebill a buyer every five days if the payment failed. You can't control the timeframe until the next billing attempt.